Can I work from the UK while my spouse is studying there?
My spouse is planning to go to the UK to study (year long course). Can I live with my spouse while he's there, and - more importantly - would I be allowed to work from there for my company in the USA?
Would a visitors visa be enough, is there a special spousal visa that would allow for this, or would I have to get a work visa?

Although it might make no difference, I don't know the UK laws, in many cases it depends on your and your spouses citizenship. I guess based on you working for a US company, that you are a US citizen?

No. The rules have changed in 2024, and dependents are only allowed if the sponsor is studying for a PhD or similar degree. See https://www.gov.uk/student-visa/family-members.
If they were studying for a PhD or similar, then you should be able to work for your US-based company with no restrictions - see https://www.ed.ac.uk/student-administration/immigration/dependants.
(This is assuming that you and your spouse are not UK citizens and that neither of you are eligible for any other type of visa that could change this answer)

Worth noting that while visitors are permitted to undertake some work relating to their employment overseas remotely from within the UK (eg responding to emails, answering phone calls or participating in remote meetings etc) the primary purpose for coming to the UK must be to undertake another permitted activity, rather than specifically to work remotely. A lengthy stay that’s not financially viable without remote working on an ongoing basis would be considered as work and is not allowed.

Working in the UK for extended periods would also have fiscal consequences (you and your employer need to declare and pay taxes and national insurance in the UK), which the US employer may not be able or willing to do. If the US employer has a UK subsidiary then transferring there is probably the simplest option. Otherwise going through an umbrella company, or going the sole trader route (with all the consequences this can have) are options.
